# How to solve gitlab yaml script invalid syntax error

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a script which for some reason is invalid with a bunch of errors generated in gitlab pipeline and ci lint such as:

1. Syntax is incorrect
2. (): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping
3. bad indentation of a sequence entry

   ```
   .publish:
     image: python:3
     script:
       - printf "const config = { apiUrl: '${API_URL}', environment: 
        '${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}', userpool_client_id: '${USERPOOL_CLIENT_ID}', 
         cognito_domain: '${COGNITO_DOMAIN}' }" > ${BUILD_DIR}/config.js
   ```

It creates an object called config and prints it into config.js file during buildtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format your script as a multiline block. One such option would be to use a [literal scalar](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688) (`|`) to preserve your new lines.

```
.publish:
  image: python:3
  script:
    - |
      printf "const config = { 
        apiUrl: '${API_URL}', 
        environment:'${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}', 
        userpool_client_id: '${USERPOOL_CLIENT_ID}', 
        cognito_domain: '${COGNITO_DOMAIN}' 
      }" > ${BUILD_DIR}/config.js
```